# Progress DB charindex syntax error

Tags: progress-4gl, progress-db

I'm trying to create a query in progress DB that gets the name portion off the email address.  This is what I have so far:

```
substring("PUB"."NAME"."INTERNET-ADDRESS", 1, CHARINDEX('@', "PUB"."NAME"."INTERNET-ADDRESS") ) as Name
```

However, I'm getting a syntax error around the CHARINDEX(...

I'm not a progress guy and knowing SQL is just enough to get me into trouble...

Do you see the error in my ways?

Comment: Can you share your entire query please?

Comment: I disconnected and can't get back in... =/  I was on a remote session with a customer to do this.

Comment: I should also mention that the "pub"."name"."internet-address" does come back with results as expected without the substring portion...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

substring("PUB"."NAME"."INTERNET-ADDRESS", 1, INSTR("PUB"."NAME"."INTERNET-ADDRESS",'@') ).

Here you have the entire suite of documentation:
https://community.progress.com/community_groups/openedge_general/w/openedgegeneral/1329.openedge-product-documentation-overview

Comment: Almost works...  I did 

substring("PUB"."NAME"."INTERNET-ADDRESS", 1, INSTR("PUB"."NAME"."INTERNET-ADDRESS",'@') -1 ) and the query runs but I get an error HY000 Bad Arguments (7487)  If I remove the -1 I dont get an error but it includes the '@'.  Weird that I get the error and it still runs though...

Comment: Nevermind; it was because there was one record that didn't have an address.  Thanks, Jensd.

Comment: Thanks! I thought CHARINDEX was in SQL-92, but INSTR did the trick!